# Oracle how to sum columns based on month number

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have a summary table for months 1 - 12 based on fyr, fund, glkey, globject.  The problem I have is summing up the months up to a given month number for that row.  I can add a `Case` expression to add like

```
WHEN  2 then  m01 + m02 
WHEN 12 then  m01 + m02 .. m12
```

Does anyone know of a loop or better way of accomplishing this?

[image: Record in SQL]

Function I created passing it 4 for month value should be 2537.50 but I get 15741.09.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gla_sum_asof_month (
    fyr   IN NUMBER  , fund  IN NUMBER  , au    IN CHAR
  , acct  IN NUMBER  , sacct IN NUMBER  , mnth  IN NUMBER  )
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  rtn_amt NUMBER(18,2) := 0;
  amt NUMBER(18,2) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(amt) INTO rtn_amt FROM (
  SELECT *
    FROM   app_reports.vw_glamounts 
  UNPIVOT
   (
     amt  FOR fmonth
     IN (m01 AS 1, m02 AS 2, m03 AS 3, m04 AS 4 , m05 AS 5 , m06 AS 6,
         m07 AS 7, m08 AS 8 , m09 AS 9, m10 AS 10, m11 AS 11, m12 AS 12)
    )
   ) a
    WHERE  a.Fiscal_Year            = fyr
          AND    a.company          = fund
          AND    a.acct_unit        = au
          AND    a.account          = acct
          AND   a. sub_account      = sacct
          AND   a.fmonth            <= mnth;  -- filter # of months

   RETURN rtn_amt;
END gla_sum_asof_month;
```

Comment: A better way would be to normalize your data model

Comment: How about as select with aggregation, using month to SUM? (out of a date - pretty much similar to what @a_horse_with_no_name said looks like a data modelling issue)  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp, that way you wouldn't need m01 m02 etc (constrain on month <=n)

Comment: I would also look to see if UNPIVOT helps. https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

You can `unpivot` your data in the first step, and then `pivot` through conditional aggregation :

```
with t2 as
(
select fyr, fund, glkey, globject, 
       row_number() over (order by col) as rn,
       sum(val) over (order by col) as m 
  from t
 unpivot 
 (
  val for col in (m01 , m02, m03, .., m12)
 )  
)
select fyr, fund, glkey, globject,
       max(case when rn = 1 then m end) as m01,
       max(case when rn = 2 then m end) as m02,
       ...
       max(case when rn =12 then m end) as m12
  from t2
 group by fyr, fund, glkey, globject
```

`order by col` is important to consider as trick for the logic.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=afe5256e73f5daf5589caa3e62261e26)</kbd>

Comment: I've created a function to call from a SQL.

Comment: I've created a function to call from a SQL but when I call it I get a number that doesn't meet any of the values I expect.  If I run just the SQL inside the function it is correct.  I tried posting the code but the window was to small. What to I do to post the code?  It's only 26 lines but goes over the characters allowed.